# Set button link behind a java script function

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onclicklistener

I want to set up the call to action link behind a java script function. But somehow it doesnt work and i cant find the problem.

```
<html>
<body>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="noreferrer" onclick="exit_offer();PreventExitPop = false" class="claim">click here</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function exit_offer() {
            window.onbeforeunload=null;
          window.location = “http://example.com”;
       }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use onclick="exit_offer()"

Comment: You can't use curly quotes (`“` and `”`) for strings. You'd have to do `window.location = "http://example.com";` (with the straight quotes).

Comment: Thank you Marco Burstein that was the mistake. =)